# Easiest way for non-technical beta testers to gather system information of their PC?

Tags: windows, diagnostic

I am starting beta testing on a new Windows application and since it does 3D rendering, system specification can be important especially as I am targeting business users; business laptops often have poor graphics.

I always try to ask for system information but for non-technical users this can be difficult; equally I don't want to make people pass on sensitive information or anything like that - I have asked people to run *dxdiag.exe* in the past.

Are there any good, free, simple tools or ideally websites which can make this simple for all concerned? I do not need loads of information just the basics of CPU, RAM and GPU.

Comment: Just use Speccy it will provide you all information you need to answer any question anyone has

Comment: The *easiest* way (for the user) may be to just build the information you need into your application, e.g. a "debugging info" button.

Comment: but that requires them to download/install it, when it may be wasting their time!

Answer (score 4):

What version of Windows? Can you ask them to take a screenshot of the System Properties (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>)?

What about `msinfo32.exe`? Export a report from there, and ask them to upload to your server (via website or email). There are also API calls for obtaining that information manually, if you are the programmer.

Comment: Dxdiag.exe is a good reporting tool as well and will be on a windows machine already.

Comment: Sadly the Sys-Prop window doesn't include graphics info, which is actually the single most important thing I'm looking for. Of installed tools, dxdiag is the most ideal - I'd love to be able to send people to a web-URL but I guess that isn't possible without plugins?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

It's incredibly detailed, arguably more so than `msinfo32`. Slightly off topic, since you are conducting a beta test, you may also be interested in `psr`, which is included with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html). I've used it before and has great summary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution the company I work for came up with was a custom data-collection program (not limited to hardware; it also gathers version information for various relevant pieces of software).  Usage instructions are basically "Run this program.  Copy the output, paste it into an email, and send it to this address".  Almost all users can manage that, especially since the program comes with a big "copy" button on the output screen.

Answer (score -1):

what browser am i using? because all they have to do is point their browser to the url, which almost everyone can do, so there literally is no technical overhead. point to url. fill out contact form that is in that document, and prepopulated with system data, might i add. imo, because of the url, this is the superior solution, at least to the one's recommended. i'm not saying it's technically superior, but so much more usable. check it out:
http://www.whatbrowseramiusing.co/

Comment: Dosen't really answer the question, considering the OP needs information on things like the GPU

Comment: man how did i miss that last sentence? my bad